# New text header line in tabular?

Tags: tables

I want to insert headers in table, but somehow I am not able to do so. The bold line in below text, I want these to just insert between rows as headers. From below code, column from 2nd to last are shifted far beyond page. I think this is due to these line are considered as row elements not just a header line. Please help.

```
\begin{tabular}{l*{6}{c}r}\hline
Data set & EPMM & BCC & TEST1 & TEST2 & TEST3 \\ \hline
```

**`IN first run of experiment with 100 ml solute \\`**

```
MAE & 1.4 & 1.4 & 1.5 & 1.8 & \\
ME  & 1.4 & 1.4 & 1.5 & 1.8 & \<b>
`IN second run of experiment with 200 ml solute\\`
```

```
MAE & 1.4 & 1.4 & 1.5 & 1.8 & \\
ME  & 1.4 & 1.4 & 1.5 & 1.8 & \<b>
`In third run of experiment with 300 ml solute\\`
```

```
MAE & 1.4 & 1.4 & 1.5 & 1.8 & \\
ME  & 1.4 & 1.4 & 1.5 & 1.8 & \\
overall MAE & 0.80 & 3.06 & 2.65 & 3.04 & 3.13 \\
overall ME  & 0.11 & 3.03 & 2.63 & 2.00 & 3.13  \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.  Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Answer (score 5):

`\multicolumn` is your friend, e.g.:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{l*{6}{c}}\hline
Data set & EPMM & BCC & TEST1 & TEST2 & TEST3 \\ \hline
\noalign{\vspace{1ex}}
\multicolumn{6}{l}{\textbf{%
  In first run of experiment with 100 ml solute}} \\
MAE & 1.4 & 1.4 & 1.5 & 1.8 & \\
ME & 1.4 & 1.4 & 1.5 & 1.8 & \\[1ex]
\multicolumn{6}{l}{\textbf{%
  In second run of experiment with 200 ml solute}} \\
MAE & 1.4 & 1.4 & 1.5 & 1.8 & \\
ME & 1.4 & 1.4 & 1.5 & 1.8 & \\[1ex]
\multicolumn{6}{l}{\textbf{%
  In third run of experiment with 300 ml solute}} \\
MAE & 1.4 & 1.4 & 1.5 & 1.8 & \\
ME & 1.4 & 1.4 & 1.5 & 1.8 & \\
overall MAE & 0.80 & 3.06 & 2.65 & 3.04 & 3.13 \\
overall ME & 0.11 & 3.03 & 2.63 & 2.00 & 3.13 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Remarks:

- I have added some space above the bold lines. It can be done by adding the
  space in the optional argument of `\\`. In the first case, there is an `\hline` inbetween, therefore the space is added via `\vspace`, smuggled in via `\noalign` that can be used at the very beginning of a line.
- The example uses six columns without the unused seventh column.

### Example that aligns the decimal numbers on the dot separator

The example uses package `dcolumn` and the `D` column specifier. The header line shows another use case for `\multicolumn`. It can also be uses for one cell for overriding the column specification of the cell.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{l*{5}{D{.}{.}{2}}}\hline
Data set &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{EPMM} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{BCC} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{TEST1} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{TEST2} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{TEST3} \\ \hline
\noalign{\vspace{1ex}}
\multicolumn{6}{l}{\textbf{%
  In first run of experiment with 100 ml solute}} \\
MAE & 1.4 & 1.4 & 1.5 & 1.8 & \\
ME & 1.4 & 1.4 & 1.5 & 1.8 & \\[1ex]
\multicolumn{6}{l}{\textbf{%
  In second run of experiment with 200 ml solute}} \\
MAE & 1.4 & 1.4 & 1.5 & 1.8 & \\
ME & 1.4 & 1.4 & 1.5 & 1.8 & \\[1ex]
\multicolumn{6}{l}{\textbf{%
  In third run of experiment with 300 ml solute}} \\
MAE & 1.4 & 1.4 & 1.5 & 1.8 & \\
ME & 1.4 & 1.4 & 1.5 & 1.8 & \\
overall MAE & 0.80 & 3.06 & 2.65 & 3.04 & 3.13 \\
overall ME & 0.11 & 3.03 & 2.63 & 2.00 & 3.13 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 4):

You can get better results with `booktabs` and `siunitx`. For the headers, use `\multicolumn`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{position=above}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\sisetup{detect-all} % we want \SI to respect font attributes

\centering

\caption{Results of the experiments}\label{tab:results}

\begin{tabular}{l*{5}{S[table-format=1.2]}}
\toprule
Data set & {EPMM} & {BCC} & {TEST1} & {TEST2} & {TEST3} \\
\midrule
\multicolumn{6}{c}{\bfseries
  In first run of experiment with \SI{100}{ml} solute} \\
MAE & 1.4 & 1.4 & 1.5 & 1.8 \\
ME  & 1.4 & 1.4 & 1.5 & 1.8 \\
\midrule
\multicolumn{6}{c}{\bfseries
  In second run of experiment with \SI{200}{ml} solute} \\
MAE & 1.4 & 1.4 & 1.5 & 1.8 & \\
ME  & 1.4 & 1.4 & 1.5 & 1.8 & \\
\midrule
\multicolumn{6}{c}{\bfseries
  In third run of experiment with \SI{300}{ml} solute} \\
MAE & 1.4 & 1.4 & 1.5 & 1.8 & \\
ME  & 1.4 & 1.4 & 1.5 & 1.8 & \\
\midrule
overall MAE & 0.80 & 3.06 & 2.65 & 3.04 & 3.13 \\
overall ME  & 0.11 & 3.03 & 2.63 & 2.00 & 3.13  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Notice that with the S-column type provided by `siunitx` you get alignment at the decimal point.